# Pass a variable between two document javascripts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am trying to make a drop down list which is made up from a php database call which returns values in a json format. What the first function, jsonload does is to return two fields of this json wrapped in an  field.
What i then want to do is pass this as a variable into the subfunction, optionload of function, forms. Where it will be added as a string. This will then give me my dropdown list for that row, and then as i add additional rows, the dropdown list is already completed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="codexworld_frm" id="form1" method="post">
<div class="field_wrapper">
<div>
    <h3><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add Field">Add POS Item</a>    </h3>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // JavaScript Document
    var globalVariable;
$(document).ready(function jsonload(data){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/test/php/psql.php", function(data)
             {
        var options = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                options +="<option value=\"" + data[i].POSID + "\">" +  data[i].Product + "</option>";
                //console.log(data[i].POSID + " " + data[i].Product);
            }

        var globalVariable=options;
        console.log(globalVariable);
    });
}); 


$(document).ready(function forms(){
        var maxField = 50; //Input fields increment limitation
        var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
        var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
        //var fieldHTML = {row :function(f){
                         //return '<h3><div>Item <input type="text" name="field_name['+f+'][]" value=""/>Material <input type="text" name="field_name['+f+'][]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove Field"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color:blue">remove_circle</i></a></div></h3>';
                        //}};
        var fieldHTML = {row :function optionload(f){
            var local = globalVariable;
            console.log(local);
            //event.preventDefault();
                         return '<div>Item<input type="text" name="field_name['+f+'][]" value=""/>Material <select name="field_name['+f+'][]"><option value=""></option>' + local + '</select><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove Field"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color:blue">remove_circle</i></a></div>';
        }};
        var x = 1; //initial field counter is 1
        $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
            if(x < maxField){
                x++;
                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML.row(x)); //Add field html
            }
            });
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
                      e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove field html
        x--;
        });
});
    </script>

    </html>
```

This is my json file, for testing

```
[
  {
    "POSID": "104",
    "Product": "10 Case Header"
  },
  {
    "POSID": "105",
    "Product": "10 Case Header"
  }
]
```

I am a beginner, and appreciate any help i can get.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues.

**First**, you are creating a variable `globalVariable` in the global scope in order to transfer data from one function to another:

```
//JavaScript Document
var globalVariable;
```

However, you are then declaring another variable (by using the `var` keyword) called `globalVariable` inside the scope of your `$.getJSON()` callback function, and assigning to *this variable* the value of `options`... not the variable in the global scope:

```
var globalVariable=options;
```

Your global `globalVariable` never actually gets anything assigned to it.

**Second**, although the code may work if `$.getJSON()` returns fast enough, `$.getJSON()` is an asynchronous function, meaning that other code, like your `$(document).ready()` callback will continue to execute after `$.getJSON()` is invoked. If your request to `http://localhost/test/php/psql.php` takes a couple second to return, the user could have already clicked on the add button, but your options may not yet be available.

You probably should wait until your `json` data has been returned, before binding the click handlers to your buttons.

This can be accomplished without the use of a global variable, too:

- Move your `forms()` function out of the `$(document).ready()`
- Put the logic in your `$.getJSON()` callback function into the `forms()` function
- Allow `forms()` to take a parameter `data`
- make `forms` your `$.getJSON()` callback function
- Get rid of `globalVariable` and `local` and use `options` instead

---

```
$(document).ready(function jsonload(){
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/test/php/psql.php", forms);
}); 

function forms(data){
// Previously in getJSON callback        
    var options = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            options +="<option value='" + data[i].POSID + "'>" +  data[i].Product + "</option>";
            //console.log(data[i].POSID + " " + data[i].Product);
        }
    // no need for globalVariable/local anymore, just use options
    //var globalVariable=options

    // Original Forms function
    var maxField = 50; //Input fields increment limitation
    var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
    var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
    var fieldHTML = {
        row: function optionload(f){
            console.log(options);
            return '<div>Item<input type="text" name="field_name['+f+'][]" value=""/>Material <select name="field_name['+f+'][]"><option value=""></option>' + options + '</select><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove Field"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color:blue">remove_circle</i></a></div>';
    }};
    var x = 1; //initial field counter is 1
    $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
        if(x < maxField){
            x++;
            $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML.row(x)); //Add field html
        }
    });
    $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove field html
        x--;
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer chester. I am very new to javascript and appreciate your help and the explanation of the issues in my code.

Comment: when i run this function in my page, i notice that the add button no longer works. thank you for explanation regarding the faults in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="codexworld_frm" id="form1" method="post">
<div class="field_wrapper">
<div>
    <h3><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="add_button" title="Add Field">Add POS Item</a>    </h3>
</div>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // JavaScript Document
    var globalVariable;
$(document).ready(function jsonload(data){
   // $.getJSON("http://localhost/test/php/psql.php", function(data)
             //{
        var options = "";
               var data =[
  {
    "POSID": "104",
    "Product": "10 Case Header"
  },
  {
    "POSID": "105",
    "Product": "10 Case Header"
  }
];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
                options +="<option value=\"" + data[i].POSID + "\">" +  data[i].Product + "</option>";
                //console.log(data[i].POSID + " " + data[i].Product);
            }

        var globalVariable=options;
        console.log(globalVariable);
    //});

        var maxField = 50; //Input fields increment limitation
        var addButton = $('.add_button'); //Add button selector
        var wrapper = $('.field_wrapper'); //Input field wrapper
        //var fieldHTML = {row :function(f){
                         //return '<h3><div>Item <input type="text" name="field_name['+f+'][]" value=""/>Material <input type="text" name="field_name['+f+'][]" value=""/><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove Field"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color:blue">remove_circle</i></a></div></h3>';
                        //}};
        var fieldHTML = {row :function optionload(f){
            var local = globalVariable;
            console.log(local);
            //event.preventDefault();
                         return '<div>Item<input type="text" name="field_name['+f+'][]" value=""/>Material <select name="field_name['+f+'][]"><option value=""></option>' + local + '</select><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove_button" title="Remove Field"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px; color:blue">remove_circle</i></a></div>';
        }};
        var x = 1; //initial field counter is 1
        $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
            if(x < maxField){
                x++;
                $(wrapper).append(fieldHTML.row(x)); //Add field html
            }
            });
        $(wrapper).on('click', '.remove_button', function(e){ //Once remove button is clicked
                      e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove field html
        x--;
        });
});
    </script>

    </html>
```